# split data based on cumulative value of column in r

Tags: r, split, dataframe

I have following type of data:

```
    myd <- data.frame (group  = c(rep(1, 15), rep(2, 15)),
                       distance = c(0, 4, 8,9,11,  14,18,19,23, 24,  29,30,35,40, 43,
                                    0, 8,9,9,12,   13,14,15,16, 18,  23,24,28, 29, 30),
                      var1 = c(1:15, 11:25), var2 = 1:30, var3 = 1:30)
    myd 

   group distance var1 var2 var3
1      1        0    1    1    1
2      1        4    2    2    2
3      1        8    3    3    3
4      1        9    4    4    4
5      1       11    5    5    5
6      1       14    6    6    6
7      1       18    7    7    7
8      1       19    8    8    8
9      1       23    9    9    9
10     1       24   10   10   10
11     1       29   11   11   11
12     1       30   12   12   12
13     1       35   13   13   13
14     1       40   14   14   14
15     1       43   15   15   15
16     2        0   11   16   16
17     2        8   12   17   17
18     2        9   13   18   18
19     2        9   14   19   19
20     2       12   15   20   20
21     2       13   16   21   21
22     2       14   17   22   22
23     2       15   18   23   23
24     2       16   19   24   24
25     2       18   20   25   25
26     2       23   21   26   26
27     2       24   22   27   27
28     2       28   23   28   28
29     2       29   24   29   29
30     2       30   25   30   30
```

I have multiple group levels (than 2 shown above). For each distance (say mile posts in highway) starts with 0 and is cumulative to end to the group. I want to split the data (make bins) in such way that each group is approximately of distance 10. The resulting split data will be like:

```
data group1subset1

          group distance var1 var2 var3
    1      1        0    1    1    1
    2      1        4    2    2    2
    3      1        8    3    3    3
    4      1        9    4    4    4
data group1subset2
    5      1       11    5    5    5
    6      1       14    6    6    6
    7      1       18    7    7    7
    8      1       19    8    8    8
data group1subset3
    9      1       23    9    9    9
    10     1       24   10   10   10
    11     1       29   11   11   11
    12     1       30   12   12   12
data group1subset4
    13     1       35   13   13   13
    14     1       40   14   14   14
data group1subset5
    15     1       43   15   15   15
=====
data group2subset1
    16     2        0   11   16   16
    17     2        8   12   17   17
    18     2        9   13   18   18
    19     2        9   14   19   19
data group2subset2
    20     2       12   15   20   20
    21     2       13   16   21   21
    22     2       14   17   22   22
    23     2       15   18   23   23
    24     2       16   19   24   24
    25     2       18   20   25   25
data group2subset3
    26     2       23   21   26   26
    27     2       24   22   27   27
    28     2       28   23   28   28
    29     2       29   24   29   29
    30     2       30   25   30   30
```

I need to automize the process as the real data is really big. Please suggest how can we do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd actually use `cut` to accomplish this:

```
maxd <- (max(myd$distance) %/% 10 * 10) + 10


transform(myd,cutdist = cut(distance, breaks = seq(0,maxd, by = 10),
                            include.lowest = TRUE))

   group distance var1 var2 var3 cumdist cutdist
1      1        0    1    1    1       0  [0,10]
2      1        4    2    2    2       4  [0,10]
3      1        8    3    3    3      12  [0,10]
4      1        9    4    4    4      21  [0,10]
5      1       11    5    5    5      32 (10,20]
6      1       14    6    6    6      46 (10,20]
7      1       18    7    7    7      64 (10,20]
8      1       19    8    8    8      83 (10,20]
9      1       23    9    9    9     106 (20,30]
10     1       24   10   10   10     130 (20,30]
11     1       29   11   11   11     159 (20,30]
12     1       30   12   12   12     189 (20,30]
13     1       35   13   13   13     224 (30,40]
14     1       40   14   14   14     264 (30,40]
15     1       43   15   15   15     307 (40,50]
16     2        0   11   16   16     307  [0,10]
17     2        8   12   17   17     315  [0,10]
18     2        9   13   18   18     324  [0,10]
19     2        9   14   19   19     333  [0,10]
20     2       12   15   20   20     345 (10,20]
21     2       13   16   21   21     358 (10,20]
22     2       14   17   22   22     372 (10,20]
23     2       15   18   23   23     387 (10,20]
24     2       16   19   24   24     403 (10,20]
25     2       18   20   25   25     421 (10,20]
26     2       23   21   26   26     444 (20,30]
27     2       24   22   27   27     468 (20,30]
28     2       28   23   28   28     496 (20,30]
29     2       29   24   29   29     525 (20,30]
30     2       30   25   30   30     555 (20,30]
```

There's actually no need to calculate cumulative distance, since you want to keep them in groups of multiples of 10

Comment: Maybe change the `to` in `seq` to `max(distance) + 10` to avoid NAs? I don't think it really matters anyway, just a suggestion.

Comment: Nice idea! I modified it a bit, such that the upper bound will always be the next multiple of 10 larger than `max(distance)`

Comment: @AndrewMacDonald great answer, thanks ... I need to split the data using the level of 'cutdist' using split. Is there way we can modify the cutdist names are named without having braces - for example 's0e10', for '(0,10]'

Comment: yep! you can give them any names you want by using the `labels` argument.  see `?cut`

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
split(myd, interaction(myd$distance %/%10, myd$group, drop=F), drop=T)
```

here we bin the distance based on how many times it's divisible by 10 and create an interaction with group to make distinct categories for each. We us that as a factor for `split()`. This puts 0 with the first group and 10 with the second so some of your example breaks are slightly different with the code, but it seems comparable.

Comment: thanks for the idea... in real my distance numbers are much bigger more digits and decimals so division stagy may be difficult to implement.

Comment: Then a `cut()` strategy is definitely more appropriate. I simply based my solution on your example data.